# Does dispelling with an opposing spell require a check or save?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

In Pathfinder there are a few spells that are effectively polar opposites, and as such have the text “counters and dispels [opposite]”.  The rules for counterspelling are spelled out fairly well, but I'm not sure about the dispelling.  If I use an opposed spell that would normally allow a saving throw and spell resistance to dispel its opposite, does that require a spell penetration check, allow a saving throw, or simply happen?

For example, the party is fighting a Wizard with Slow on his list.  The party casts Haste.  The next round the Wizard casts Slow on the party to dispel Haste.  What rolls, if any, are required for the dispel to be successful?

Answer (score 7):

In your case, Slow dispels Haste when the wizard casts it. No check is required.

Normally, only certain spells, like *dispel magic* can be used to get rid of an effect after casting. If you ready an action to counterspell, you can automatically cancel an enemy spell, with no check required, by using your readied action, and expending the **same** spell as the one being cast (or another same-or-higher-level spell of the same school, with the Improved Counterspelling feat). When counterspelling this way, a Spellcraft (DC 15+spell level) is first required to identify the spell being cast. *Dispel magic* and similar spells can also be used to counterspell, requiring a caster level check as listed in the spell's description.

Some spells have a specific notation in their descriptions that an opposite spell counters and dispels it. In those specific cases, the opposite spell **can** be used after the fact, and no check is required. Casting the opposite spell will negate the effect of the original.

Ex:

> *Darkness* can be used to counter **or dispel** any light spell of equal or lower level.

(PF264; emphasis mine).

**Edit:**
Updated the counterspelling description to mention the Spellcraft check, etc.

Comment: Is there any specific description as to how dispelling works other than the description of _dispel magic_?

Comment: You'd still need to make the Spellcraft check to identify the spell being cast.  All that line means is that you can use it to counter the opposite in addition to using it to counter itself.

Comment: @okeefe: Not as far as I know. I just noted that it says counter "or dispel" in the spell description. Since a check isn't required when using an opposite spell to counterspell, I inferred that it's not required when using an opposite spell to dispel.

Comment: @Bobson: You're correct. The question though is about whether he can dispel a continuous effect after the fact by casting the opposite spell, and what that entails.

Comment: @RMorrisey - Ooh, good point. I missed that.

Comment: @RMorrisey I think you're just confusing the effects of counterspell (automatic negation with a successful Spellcraft check and cast of the counter spell, as the original spell is cast) and dispel (ending a spell already active, requires a caster check, described in _dispel magic_).

Comment: @okeefe: I sent an e-mail to Tim Shadow, the maintainer of the Pathfinder SRD FAQ, with the OP's question and a link to this post. Hopefully we can get an official ruling.

Answer (score 6):

Tim Shadow replied to my e-mail with a third interpretation:

> First I am happy help but not sure how "official" the answer is and
>   two a GM could interpret the answer differently.
>
> Going with your example at the end with the Wizard.  So the party has
>   Haste and the Wizard casts Slow on the party so each PC has to make a
>   Save vs the Slow.  If they fail the save they the Slow removes/dispels
>   the haste with no other effect.  If the player makes his save he is
>   not affected by Slow and there for gets to keep his Haste spell.
>
> Basically it works this way as your not actually affected by Slow
>   until you have failed your Save.  Or if you had Spell Resistance Slow
>   would have to overcome the SR and then fail your save before it would
>   remove the Haste.
>
> Hope that helps.

Comment: I disagree. If a spell states in its description that it "counters and dispels" an opposing spell, then casting the former spell on subjects affected by the latter should result in the two automatically canceling each other. In this specific example, when someone is under the effects of *haste* and you cast *slow* on them, you're using it to dispel the effect -- no saves, no checks, just a net effect of zero.

Comment: I like this interpretation far more. The Dispelling property requires the spell to affect you, and normally you get to roll a Saving throw *before* it affects you. This explanation would be the behavior I'd expect and use if I had to rule in a hurry instead of looking it up.

Answer (score -1):

In general, you can't dispel with an opposing spell. The opposing spell is only relevant if you are [counterspelling](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magic.html#counterspells), which negates the target spell as it is being cast.

You can dispel an already-cast, active spell by using the [targeted dispel form of *dispel magic*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/dispelMagic.html), which requires a dispel check.

However, *slow* specifically states that it counters and dispels *haste*.  Treat it as a multiple targeted (as per *slow*), targeted form of *dispel magic*.  Possible rolls would be: Spell resistance of each of the *slow*'s targets, then a single dispel check (1d20 + the wizard's caster level) versus the DC of the *haste* (11 + the caster's spell level).

Comment: So then what happens if you cast slow on a hasted target? Does it completely overwrite the haste?

Comment: Oh, _slow_ specifically mentions that it dispels _haste_.  Let me update my answer.

Comment: I disagree with this answer. No check is required to dispel an opposite spell. Only spells like *dispel magic* require a caster level check, and SR is not mentioned in the dispelling or counterspelling rules. (Likewise, the *dispel magic* spell does not allow SR.)

Comment: Is there any rules basis for your specific example?

Comment: I could see the argument that since Slow is targeting the party, it should require saves and SR checks, but that's not the intent of the rules IMO; you are using the spell to counter another spell, rather than using it to debuff other characters.

Comment: It's too late to counter if the _haste_ is already up.  You have to dispel to get rid of the effect, and the only rules I know for that are under _dispel magic_.  _Slow_ is acting like _dispel magic_ specifically for _haste_.  If there are general dispelling rules, I'd love to see them.