# Can a spell always counterspell itself?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic, counterspelling

The counterspell rules in *Pathfinder* say some spells can be used to counter other spells (like, say, Darkness can counterspell light spells). But does this override the regular counterspelling rule? In short, can Darkness still counterspell Darkness?

*(Note: I'm on smartphone, the ask page doesn't tell me if this question is already asked)*

Comment: Note, though, that counterspelling a spell requires you to be in range...and spells such as Darkness and Light generally have Touch range, meaning you have to be able to touch the caster...highly impractical in most situations, even if it is technically possible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### A spell can be used to counterspell a spell of the same name *plus* any additional spells the spell lists

[Counterspells](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Counterspells) says, "It is possible to cast any spell as a counterspell," then, later, continues, saying, "Some spells can counter *other* specific spells, often those with diametrically opposed effects" (emphasis mine). These other spells that can be countered by a specific spell are *in addition* to the spell being able to counterspell itself. (Also see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/69243/8610).)

Answer (score 7):

#### Yes, unless the spell explicitly says otherwise.

From the PFSRD [on counterspelling](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Counterspells) (*emphasis mine*):

> To complete the action, you must then cast an appropriate spell. *As a general rule, a spell can only counter itself*. If you are able to cast the same spell and you have it prepared (or have a slot of the appropriate level available), you cast it, creating a counterspell effect. If the target is within range, both spells automatically negate each other with no other results.
>
> **Specific Exceptions**
> Some spells can counter other specific spells, often those with diametrically opposed effects.

Unless the spell's description explicitly says that it *can't* be used to counterspell itself, then it *can*.

Comment: Do you have any examples of spells that cannot counterspell themselves?

Comment: @Walt No, and I don't believe there are any. Specific beats general, however, so if a spell's description *did* state that the spell could not be used to counterspell itself, that would trump the general rules.

Comment: @Walt - A case can be made that *dispel magic* can't be used to automatically counterspell itself, and that trying to do so triggers the general "use *dispel magic* as counterspell" rules instead.  Whether or not there's any clarification on that, or whether it'd hold up at in actual play, I don't know.

Comment: @Bobson: can you back up this case? Given the general rule a *dispel magic* should be able to automatically counter an other *dispel magic*.

Comment: @AnneAunyme From the "Counterspell" section of *dispel magic*: "**When dispel magic is used in this way**, the spell targets a spellcaster and is cast as a counterspell. Unlike a true counterspell, however, dispel magic may not work; **you must make a dispel check to counter the other spellcaster’s spell.**"  It's a spell-specific rule about using it as a counterspell, which would override the general case.

Comment: @AnneAunyme If you're interested in that corner case you should take it to a new question.

Comment: @ObliviousSage: I am now close enough to being certain on this point that I don't anymore feel the need to ask for it.