# What, exactly, happens when boots of speed are activated under a slow spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic-items

A user came in to one of my Discord chats asking, what happens when I'm hit by *slow* and activate my *boots of speed*? *Haste* and *slow* spells descriptions both indicate, "This spell counters and dispels the other." What does that mean?

- Do I need to roll a check of any sort?
- Are any of my allies freed from the *slow*?
- Are my *boots of speed* deactivated for 1d4 rounds, per the description of *dispel magic*?
- How many spells are considered to have been dispelled for the purpose of a theoretical ability such as as follows?

  > Whenever an effect created by a spell or spell-like ability is dispelled within 30 feet of you, you heal 1 hit point per 2 character levels (minimum 1).

Comment: You might be interested in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/69243/8610).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What it means when a spell counters or dispels another spell is addressed both by [a specific entry in the FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qjy) and in answers to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/69243/8610). In short, if a spell says that it dispels another spell, the spell's normal effect doesn't occur and, instead, typically, the spell *automatically* dispels that opposing spell—no check needed, and SR does not apply. Usually even the efficacy of the spells involved is unimportant: for example, a level 1 caster that manages to cast a [*haste*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/haste/) spell *automatically* dispels a level 20 caster's [*slow*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/slow/) spell, and, similarly, a caster's [*daylight*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/daylight/) spell that's modified by the feat [Heighten Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/heighten-spell-metamagic-final/) to a 9th-level spell dispels *automatically* any 8th-level or lower spell that possesses the [descriptor](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Descriptor-) darkness, even were the modified *daylight* spell's caster to cast it at caster level 8 from a custom staff and the darkness spell were cast at caster level 15.

When a wearer takes a free action to activate the [*boots of speed*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/boots-of-speed/), the wearer usually gains the effects of the [*haste*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/haste/) spell, but this GM would rule that if the wearer of the *boots of speed* activates them while affected by the spell [*slow*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/slow/), the *haste* effect that's normally bestowed by the *boots* is negated  and, instead, the *slow* spell effect is automatically dispelled on the wearer *only*. (Each creature affected by the spell *slow* needs to be freed from the *slow* spell's effect individually; [that FAQ entry](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qjy) covers this eventuality specifically using as an example a *haste* spell dispelling a *slow* spell on some affected creatures.) This GM would rule that this costs 1 round of the *boots*' 10 rounds/day *haste* effect.

(It's possible that another GM may rule differently: a legacy item from *Pathfinder*'s antecedent *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5*, [the *boots of speed* inherited almost verbatim its text from its predecessor](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#boots-of-speed), therefore both texts say that, upon the *boots*' activation, the wearer can "act as though affected by a *haste* spell." A GM may rule that since the *boots* don't *really* cast a *haste* spell, the *slow* effect continues. In such a case, the GM must determine how the wearer of activated *boots* is affected by the *slow* effect.)

If the GM agrees that the *boots*' *haste*-like effect dispels the *slow* effect, the wearer of the *boots* has so far only taken one free action this turn to activate the *boots*. Unless the GM enforces an arbitrary limit on the number of free actions a creature can take in a round—which, by the way, the GM totally *can*—, the wearer of the *boots* can on the same turn also take *another* free action to activate the *boots* a *second* time so that the wearer can actually benefit from the *haste* effect of the *boots* now that the *slow* effect has been dispelled by the *boots*' previous activation. In doing so, the wearer would exhaust a second round of the *boots*' 10 rounds per day.

With regard to the special ability the question quotes, assuming the GM agrees that a spell affecting *you* is a spell within 30 ft. of *you* (I mean, *this* GM would, I guess), then, upon the *haste* effect of the *boots* dispelling the *slow* spell, the wearer of the *boots* would heal 1 hp per 2 character levels. Likewise, were a creature that possesses that special ability to be within range of the *boots*' wearer when the *slow* effect is dispelled, that creature would benefit from that special ability similarly.

Comment: The special ability quoted, for this scenario, may belong to someone else. What matters is how many times it triggers.

Comment: Work and life got in the way of me giving a proper comment, but my main issue with this answer is that it doesn't address the difference between casting Haste, and using an item which "allows the user to act as if under the effect of" Haste. While casting Haste clearly dispels the Slow, I disagree that activating an item (for one round) would.

Comment: @DannyCuppen Once again, thank you for your feedback. I took a stab at addressing your concerns.

Comment: Thai satisfied my concerns. Having read the relevant rules, I can't really see any definitive ruling supporting either interpretation either.