# Can boots of speed be activated multiple times in a round?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

Can boots of speed be activated twice in a round?

Say for instance you are under the effects of *slow*. So you activate the boots to counter/dispel *slow*. Are you now able to activate them a second time (using a second charge) to now be under the effects of *haste* for the one round?

*Boots of speed* are one of the few items which are activated as a free action which why this could be possible.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Yes, that answers that boots of speed can dispel the slow, but doesnt answer the multiple activation

Comment: Relevant: [What exactly happens when boots of speed are activated under a slow spell](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/121992/what-exactly-happens-when-boots-of-speed-are-activated-under-a-slow-spell)

Answer (score 4):

## No

From the description of [Boots of Speed](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/a-b/boots-of-speed/),

> As a free action, the wearer of boots of speed can click her heels together, letting her act *as though affected by a haste spell* for up to 10 rounds each day.

(emphasis mine)

Note that you do not *expend a charge to cast a spell* from the boots, you *activate them* instead which lets you to *act as if affected* by a spell for a round.

Basically, the boots have two states: inactive and active, and they can remain in active state for up to 10 rounds per day. There is no "double active" state that expends two charges per round anywhere in description.

I would also note that since Boots of Speed don't actually cast a spell but activate a spell-like effect on wearer, the interaction between them is more complicated. I couldn't find any FAQ or RAW on that, but I personally would rule that the *slow* effect is not dispelled but suppressed while the boots are activated. YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

If the GM rules that taking a free action to activate the [*boots of speed*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/a-b/boots-of-speed/) dispels a [*slow*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/slow/) effect affecting the wearer—[in the same way that a *haste* spell automatically dispels a *slow* spell](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qjy)—, then the *boots*' wearer may be able to take a second free action to activate again the *boots of speed* so that the wearer can also benefit from the [*haste*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/haste/) effect the *boots* provide… [so long as the GM hasn't put an arbitrary limit on the number of free actions a creature can take on its turn](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Free-Actions), a right the GM can exercise.

Whether activating the *boots* twice in a round—once to dispel the *slow* effect and a second time to get the *haste* benefit—spends 1 or 2 rounds of the boots' 10 rounds per day is for the GM to decide. (This GM would rule the wearer spends 1 of the *boots*' rounds to dispel the *slow* effect then spends 1 of the *boots*' rounds to benefit for 1 round from the *haste* effect, but this reader can easily imagine an argument for both effects combined spending only 1 round of the *boots*' 10 rounds per day.)

To be clear, if the GM rules that the effects of the *boots* dispel a *slow* effect, that *slow* effect ends instantaneously: the *slow* effect isn't, for instance, merely suppressed while the *boots* are in operation, but, instead, the *slow* effect affecting the wearer is just straight-up *gone.*

---

***Note:*** More about how spells counter and dispel other spells [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/69243/8610). More about boots of speed *is [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/121992/8610).*

Comment: The only problem is that Boots of Speed don't actually cast *haste* on you. It only "allows you to act as if you're under effect" of *haste*.

Comment: @Draco-S The question asks, "Say for instance you are under the effects of slow. So you activate the boots to counter/dispel slow. Are you now able to activate them a second time (using a second charge) to now be under the effects of haste for the one round?" In other words, the question presupposes that activating the *boots* dispels *slow.* An answer can certainly say, "That doesn't work," but an answer can also say—like this one does—"***If*** the GM rules that taking a free action to activate the *boots of speed* dispels a *slow* effect…" (emphases mine).

Comment: @Draco-S (Also, I think I'd take a break from playing with that GM that said to me, "Because your PC only acts *as if* he's affected by a *haste* spell because of his magic boots and is not *actually* affected by a *haste* spell from his magic boots, I'm going to make up something that will screw over your PC rather than going with *haste* dispels *slow*.")

Comment: If we read a question that way, sure. However magic items don't really work this way. Otherwise, 12k gold for an item that can dispel *slow* (a 3rd level spell) up to **ten times a day** sounds **way** too low.

Comment: @Draco-S I'm not sure how else to read the question: the question says what happens, and—to make sure that it was clear that it is the GM's call, I included a couple of *if*s. And we'll have to disagree that a 12,000-gp item that can dispel a *specific* 3rd-level spell (or maybe even spell-like effect) 10/day is underpriced. Really, the *boots* are more expensive than a *wand of dispel magic*, for instance, and in nearly 20 years at this game and its forebear I've seen *haste* dispel *slow*, like, twice. (To be fair, though, I don't know your games; maybe *slow* is a bigger deal in them?)

Comment: Consider this: spell-like abilities that all but replicate similarly-named spells, cannot be used to counter spells and cannot be countered by spells; they can only be dispelled by *Dispel Magic* or similar effect. Spell-like effects produced by magic items are even further away from original spells, so allowing them to counter spells is even less justified. (Also, did @ mention work this time?)

Comment: @Draco-S This isn't about *countering* a spell, though, but about *dispelling* a spell, and a *dispel magic* ability works just as well as an actual *dispel magic* spell for that purpose. Out of curiosity, were this discussion about something else other than *haste* and *slow* like a [*glorious*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/glorious/) weapon drawn in the area of a [*darkness*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/darkness/) spell, would we still be having it?

Comment: @Draco-S (A user is alerted automatically when a comment's added to the user's question or answer, so there's no need for an `@username` if you're trying to get the original asker or answerer's attention.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89870/discussion-between-draco-s-and-hey-i-can-chan).

Answer (score 2):

## No

[Haste](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/haste/) and [Slow](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/slow/) spells are listed as counters of each other yes, but both also mention that multiple castings of the same spell don't stack.
As the boots provide a haste effect, but spread it over the course of 10 rounds of the wearer's choosing in a day it is not cleanly comparable to a single casting of the [Haste](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/haste/) spell which lasts 1 round per level as does the [Slow](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/slow/) spell.

The most logical course of action is to have the activation of the boots temporarily suppress the [Slow](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/slow/) effect. This should be on the boots' wearer only (not other targets, and definitely NOT dispelling the [Slow](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/slow/) spell), and for only those rounds that the wearer chooses to be under the effects of the boots.

If the boots' wearer were to attempt to click them (activate) again while they were already temporarily suppressing the effects of the [Slow](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/slow/) spell then this would be an attempt to stack the [Haste](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/haste/) effect which is specifically called out as not being possible in the spell's text.